# Como faço para o SQL validar campos específicos

Tags: php, sql

Tenho o seguinte código feito pelo **Amon**:

```
select 
  id,
  disponibilidade,
  tipo 
from 
  clientes 
where 
  cliente = '$cliente' 
  AND status = '2' 
  AND (tipo <> '0' AND (disponibilidade <> '0'  OR vanual <> '0' OR vtemporada <> '0'))
```

Preciso que ele exiba quantos **clientes** possuem um **TIPO IGUAL DE ZERO** e que não tenha pelos menos um dos campos **disponibilidade** OU **vanual** OU **vtemporada** preenchidos.

Muito Obrigado!

Comment: Troca o `=` por `<>` em diponibilidade, vnaul, vtemporada.

Comment: Tente assim: `select id,disponibilidade,tipo from clientes where cliente = '$cliente' AND status = '2' AND tipo <> '0' AND (disponibilidade <> '0'  OR vanual <> '0' OR vtemporada <> '0')`

Comment: @ramaral deu não!

Comment: Coloque na pergunta:
- Os nomes e tipos das colunas utilizadas (id, disponibilidade, tipo, cliente, status, vanual e vtemporada).
- Exemplos de linhas que é suposto mostrar e não mostrar e porquê.

Comment: Afinal é `tipo <> 0` ou `tipo = 0`?

Answer (score -1):

Como você mesmo disse, você utilizará a clausula **AND**. Sua query ficará conforme abaixo:

```
select 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN tipo = 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) [TIPO_ZERO],
  COUNT(CASE WHEN tipo <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) [TIPO_DIFERENTE_ZERO]
from 
  clientes 
where 
  cliente = '$cliente' 
  AND status = '2' 
  AND (disponibilidade <> '0'  OR vanual <> '0' OR vtemporada <> '0')
```

Comment: Amigo, refiz minha pergunta com a sua SQL, pode me ajudar?

Comment: @GladisonNeuzaPerosini, editei a resposta.

Comment: Deu erro, não foi possível executar a SQL. Colei do jeito que postou!

Comment: Fiz a correção, removi o [TIPO_ZERO] e [TIPO_DIFERENTE_ZERO]. Mas o resultado não bateu com as informações contidas no banco de dados.